# Row numbering not applied as expected

Tags: sql, oracle

I am updating an existing report in SQL Developer, previously produced by someone else. It appears that ordering in one part of the script is not functioning as intended.

The following part of the script appears to work fine (originally a CTE, slightly amended for the purpose of this post):

```
    select p.person_id person_id
        , p.full_name name
        , date_of_birth date_of_birth
/*        , p.gender gender
        , (select e.ethnicity_category || case when e.sub_ethnicity_category is not null then ' - ' || e.sub_ethnicity_category end from dm_ethnicities e where e.ethnicity_code = p.full_ethnicity_code) ethnicity
        , case when exists (select 1 from disability d where d.person_id = p.person_id) then 'Yes' else 'No' end disability
*/        , ppc.category
        , wsp.workflow_id workflow_id 
        , wsp.workflow_step_id pathway_plan_step_id
        , wst.description step_description
        , to_char(wsp.started_on, 'DD/MM/YYYY') pathway_step_start_date
        , to_char(wsp.completed_on, 'DD/MM/YYYY') pathway_step_end_date
        , wsp.step_status pathway_step_status
        , fa.date_pathway
        , fa.date_of_next_pathway
        , round(((params.snapshot_date - nvl(fa.date_pathway, wsp.started_on))/(365.25/12)),2) months_since_plan
/*        , (select listagg(wnat.description, ', ') within group (order by wnat.description) 
                from dm_workflow_links wl 
                inner join dm_workflow_nxt_action_types wnat on wnat.workflow_next_action_type_id=wl.workflow_next_action_type_id 
                inner join dm_workflow_steps ws on ws.workflow_step_id = wl.target_step_id 
                where wl.source_step_id=wsp.workflow_step_id and ws.step_status <> 'CANCELLED') next_actions_of_pathway
*/        , row_number() over (partition by p.person_id order by wsp.started_on) pp_order_first
    from dm_persons p
    inner join params on 1=1
    inner join pp_cohort ppc
    on ppc.person_id=p.person_id
    left join dm_workflow_steps_people_vw wsp
    on wsp.person_id=p.person_id and wsp.workflow_step_type_id in (75,193) and wsp.cancelled_on is null  --Develop Pathway Plan, Review Pathway Plan
    left join dm_workflow_step_types wst
    on wst.workflow_step_type_id=wsp.workflow_step_type_id
    left join form_answers fa
    on fa.workflow_step_id=wsp.workflow_step_id
    where add_months(p.date_of_birth, 16*12) <= params.snapshot_date --16+
    and wsp.step_status = 'COMPLETED'
    and p.person_id = 512937
```

Which provides the following output:
[output with correct row ordering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8r58V.png)

However, when looking at the next part of the script (another CTE that has been amended for this post), the row numbering is not applied as expected:

```
, pathway as
    (
    select p.person_id person_id
        , p.full_name name
        , date_of_birth date_of_birth
/*        , p.gender gender
        , (select e.ethnicity_category || case when e.sub_ethnicity_category is not null then ' - ' || e.sub_ethnicity_category end from dm_ethnicities e where e.ethnicity_code = p.full_ethnicity_code) ethnicity
        , case when exists (select 1 from disability d where d.person_id = p.person_id) then 'Yes' else 'No' end disability
*/        , ppc.category
        , wsp.workflow_id workflow_id 
        , wsp.workflow_step_id pathway_plan_step_id
        , wst.description step_description
        , to_char(wsp.started_on, 'DD/MM/YYYY') pathway_step_start_date
        , to_char(wsp.completed_on, 'DD/MM/YYYY') pathway_step_end_date
        , wsp.step_status pathway_step_status
        , fa.date_pathway
        , fa.date_of_next_pathway
        , round(((params.snapshot_date - nvl(fa.date_pathway, wsp.started_on))/(365.25/12)),2) months_since_plan
/*        , (select listagg(wnat.description, ', ') within group (order by wnat.description) 
                from dm_workflow_links wl 
                inner join dm_workflow_nxt_action_types wnat on wnat.workflow_next_action_type_id=wl.workflow_next_action_type_id 
                inner join dm_workflow_steps ws on ws.workflow_step_id = wl.target_step_id 
                where wl.source_step_id=wsp.workflow_step_id and ws.step_status <> 'CANCELLED') next_actions_of_pathway
*/        , row_number() over (partition by p.person_id order by wsp.started_on) pp_order_first
    from dm_persons p
    inner join params on 1=1
    inner join pp_cohort ppc
    on ppc.person_id=p.person_id
    left join dm_workflow_steps_people_vw wsp
    on wsp.person_id=p.person_id and wsp.workflow_step_type_id in (75,193) and wsp.cancelled_on is null  --Develop Pathway Plan, Review Pathway Plan
    left join dm_workflow_step_types wst
    on wst.workflow_step_type_id=wsp.workflow_step_type_id
    left join form_answers fa
    on fa.workflow_step_id=wsp.workflow_step_id
    where add_months(p.date_of_birth, 16*12) <= params.snapshot_date --16+
    )


    select p.person_id 
        , p.pathway_plan_step_id
        , p.step_description
        , p.pathway_step_start_date
        , p.date_pathway
        , p.date_of_next_pathway
        , p.months_since_plan 
        , row_number() over (partition by p.person_id order by p.pathway_step_start_date desc) pp_order_latest
    from pathway p
    where p.pathway_step_status='COMPLETED'
    and p.person_id = 512937
```

[incorrect ordering based on PATHWAY_STEP_START_DATE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UF1AH.png)

Comment: What data type is p.pathway_step_start_date? If you converted to CHAR, it may not sort as you expect.

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text

Comment: Please read these two links; [mre] and [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that in 1 query sorting is based on `dm_workflow_steps_people_vw.started_on` which has `date` type. For second query sorting is based on `varchar2` column, because source  of `p.pathway_step_start_date` is `to_char(wsp.started_on, 'DD/MM/YYYY')`. Sorting applied to `date` is like sorting numbers, but sorting for `varchar2` columns is done alphabetically (so typically from left to right by comparing char to char), as a result for `varchar2`:

`29/10/2020` is "greater" than
`12/01/2023` because  first char `2` is greater than `1`.

You've got 2 options:

1. select original `wsp.started_on` column without converting data types and use it for sorting
2. you can change text format for date to `YYYY/MM/DD` which will give you the same order as for sorting based on `date` type.

I would recommend first one, because sorting dates (which is a kid of a number) is going to be faster than sorting text.